# How many of Philip José Farmers books were actually banned in the United States?

Tags: philip-jose-farmer

After reading my first banned book, "A Feast Unknown", I am curious to know how many other P.J. Farmer books were banned in the U.S.A.?

Comment: If it's banned in the U.S., how come I can find it from a number of different U.S. dealers from Amazon?  Unless you're talking about specific towns or school boards, books aren't banned in the entire U.S. - and if it's banned in specific places, you'd need to explain that and give more specifications.

Comment: It was banned in the US when it was first published and was later removed from the list. Censorship was rampant back when this book was intially released and "AFU" was considered too graphic.

Comment: @MajorStakcings: That's right.  I forgot about the term paper I did and how books and movies were censored on grounds of porno -- but I don't think it was nationally, was it?  I think those cases (if I remember!) were usually local or state governments, weren't they?

Comment: You might want to try to define what you mean by *"Censorship was rampant"* a little more carefully. Relatively few things were *"banned in the U.S.A."* as such, though many were excluded from public libraries, school libraries, most bookstores, etc. These actions were rarely federal in scope.

Comment: Is there any evidence that "A feast unknown" was **banned**? Judging from its description, it doesn't even remotely fit to be in a school library, and probably qualifies as enough of erotica/porn to be normally excluded from public libraries. Was it removed from collections/circulation when compared to **similar works**? I mean, they don't usually have De Sade's book in most libraries/bookstores either, doesn't mean it is "banned".

Comment: Ouch. Try as I may, the web isn't supporting my memory. I was positive the book cover claimed the book had been banned. I'll do a physical search for my copy before bailing out of this potentialy errant question.

Comment: [Banned & challenged books](http://www.ala.org/advocacy/banned) is a good resource for books that have been subjected to the attention of nannies in various ways. If you dig you can find some lists *including* descriptions of the nature of the pressure that the books were subjected to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, the answer is the sum of zero PJF books were banned. I was sure when I asked the question at least one,"A Feast Unknown", was on the list of banned books and then removed. There is nothing on his homepage or any of the book sellers pages to indicate the book was anything more than controversal. I promise I'll research my questions before posting the next one..